# How does Azure web service deployment work locally?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, pickle, azure-machine-learning-service

Azure ML provides client libraries (e.g. azureml for Python) for dataset management and model deploying. From what I understand, the custom algorithm would be serialized as a Pickle file, but I'm not sure what happens after that. If I have a custom model with a deep NN architecture and set up a web service for training and another for scoring, do I still need the machine that the model was developed on for the web services to run? I found this on the azureml documentation that was helpful:

> If a function has no source file associated with it (for example, you're developing inside of a REPL environment) then the functions byte code is serialized. If the function refers to any global variables those will also be serialized using Pickle. In this mode all of the state which you're referring to needs to be already defined (e.g. your published function should come after any other functions you are calling).
>
> If a function is saved on disk then the entire module the function is defined in will be serialized and re-executed on the server to get the function back. In this mode the entire contents of the file is serialized and the order of the function definitions don't matter.

What if the function uses a library like TensorFlow or Keras? Can someone explain what happens after the Pickle model is created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the model.pkl file, zip it, and upload it into Azure Machine Learning Studio as a new dataset. Then add the python module and connect it to your newly generated zip.

You can now use it inside the AML Studio experiment. To use the model add the following code in your python module:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pickle

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    sys.path.insert(0,".\Script Bundle")
    model = pickle.load(open(".\Script Bundle\model.pkl", 'rb'))
    pred = model.predict(dataframe1)
    return pd.DataFrame([pred[0]]),
```

[You may find this post useful](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2018/04/25/deploying-externally-generated-pythonr-models-as-web-services-using-azure-machine-learning-studio/)

Comment: Thanks Alibek! This is really helpful.